# Android app doesn't login by error: org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils

Tags: java, android, postgresql, jdbc, authentication

when I try to do login in my android app occurs the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:279)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
 at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.makeConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:266)
 at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:187)
 at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:172)
 at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:243)
 at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:197)
 at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:277)
 at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:366)
 at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:480)
 at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForEq(BaseDaoImpl.java:253)
 at com.discurs.app.login.LoginFragment$1.onClick(LoginFragment.java:61)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17431)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Some code:

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = new PostgreSqlDBHelper().createConnectionSource();
Dao<UserVO, String> userDAO = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, UserVO.class);
List<UserVO> listUserVO = userDAO.queryForEq("username", userName.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
```

I use Ormlite to manage all database connections. All methods are from ormlite framework.

I cannot find any information about this error: java.lang.VerifyError: org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils

The minimum API version of the app is 16 (Jelly Bean)

I have done test (with physical and virtual devices) with all API's available since the minimum of my app.

The conclusion is that crash with:

- Android Jelly Bean (API version: 16/17/18)
- Android KitKat (API version: 19/20)

The next versions of android works correctly.

Please help me to find some solution or any idea of why it's occurs.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried and how it worked out. See: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: I tried to do this action with all availables API's since 16 with physical and virtual devices and crash when it tries to get the "TimeZone" on Ormlite framework code. What has android 6 and 7 that this error doesn't success? (I have updated the question if this helps to solve the problem)

Comment: @Mk14, which pgjdbc version are you using? Would you please try pgjdbc 42.2.0.jre6?